# How to make a running count

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

New to Stacks. I've been trying to make running count at Column A. Achieved that below but can't figure out how to reset it to 1 on the next Apple or another set of Orange.
Appreciate the help.
Many thanks!

```
=IF(C2:C = "Shop", COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2:B),1)
```

```
A |----B----|----C----|
1 |--Start--|       
1 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
2 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
3 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
4 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--Start--|   
1 |--Orange-|---Shop--|
2 |--Orange-|---Shop--|
3 |--Orange-|---Shop--|
4 |--Orange-|---Shop--|
1 |--Start--|   
5 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
6 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
7 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--Start--|
```

Example 2:

```
A |----B----|----C----|
1 |--Start--|       
1 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--TEXT---|
1 |--TEXT---|
2 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--TEXT---|
3 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--TEXT---|
4 |--Apple--|---Shop--|
1 |--Start--|
```

Comment: Someone manage to solve my problem based on example 2. I'll share it here if it will help others. Let me know if i'm breaking any rules.
[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/x4a5EMhRvMI;context-place=starred)
`=IF(C1="Shop",ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(IF(ROW(B$1:B1)>=VLOOKUP(ROW(),FILTER(ROW(B$1:B1),B$1:B1="Start"),1),B$1:B1),B1)),1)`

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
=IF(and(C2 = "shop",B2=B1), A1+1,1)
```

#### How to Use

Put into cell a2, and fill down to any other cell.

#### Explanation

Using the `and` function to apply two conditions to meet. When a new string is introduced, it will cause the condition check to fail and set the count to back to one. Only when both condition meet, does the count continue.

Comment: Thanks @Jarad. That works for the current example. What happens if there's other info in between those apple & orange?

Comment: The script above looks to see if the cell above it is the same and then adds to the count - assuming that the cell adjacent to the one above has the string "shop" in it. Unless we define something as the beginning and end of a selection - e.g., the word "start", the issue will exist regardless. When I first started working on the issue, I was trying to use match to located the nearest "start" string, for your issue. However, I realized that I was assuming that start was the beginning and end of a group.